# How do I download an Apache Java API?

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is a really basic question. I'm a college sophomore and I have no experience downloading APIs to use with Java, but I'm working on a personal project in which I need to be able to read in Microsoft Excel files. I'm trying to download Apache POI, which I saw recommended here. I might just be dumb, but I can't figure out where I should be downloading it to or how to verify the integrity of the files, which the download page says it "essential".

The download page is here: http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.17. If someone could just give me an idea of how to do this, that would be great, because I'm sure it's a skill that will help me in the future.

Comment: The [Binary Distribution](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.17-bin) section provides both a zip and a tar of the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True. you are a beginner to world of coding. So try to take things one at a time and also would help if you inculcate good habits in the process.

1. To start would, would recommend to download an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), which would assist in you writing the code with ease. (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/oxygen2)
2. Next google up about Maven (alternatives are there like gradle, ant etc.). Think of this as App store on Mac. You can give details about what you require and it will take care of downloading and putting them in your project class path.
3. Create your first Maven project in Eclipse (https://wiki.jasig.org/display/UPM32/Creating+a+Simple+Maven+Project)
4. Last add the POI dependency to your `pom.xml` file (configuration file where you define which java API's you want to download and use in your project, like a shopping cart for JAVA good). The maven dependency for POI is something like follows.

> ```
> <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>     <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
>     <version>3.17</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

Now you are setup to have a good crack at your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is very helpful!

Comment: Why are you recommending such an ancient version of Apache POI?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Just download the zip file, and uzip it.  Then put the .jar file in on the Java classpath.  A better option would be to use Maven or Gradle, and add POI as a dependency.  This will auto download, and verify the dependency.

[Maven Central - POI](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cpoi%7C3.17%7Cjar)

[Intro to Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)

[Intro to Gradle](https://gradle.org/training/intro-to-gradle/)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help!